# Equivalence Relation : $5x - 2y$ divisible by $3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

In $\mathbb Z$: define $xRy \iff 3\mid(5x - 2y).$ Prove $R$ is an equivalence relation.

First I proved that it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

After that, I tried to find possible partitions of it ( $\prod$R ).

I started with $0$:

$$\begin{align}  (0)&= \{ x \in \mathbb Z \mid xR0\} \\&= \{  x \in \mathbb Z \mid \exists k\in\mathbb Z(5x = 3k)\} \\&= \{  x \in \mathbb Z\mid \exists k(x=3k) \},\end{align}$$ since 3 and 5 are coprime then 3 divides x

Now I tried $1$:

$(1) = \{x \in \mathbb Z |xR1\} = \{x \in \mathbb Z \mid\exists k(5x = 3k + 1 )\}$ , how do I continue?

Is $\prod R = \{\{3k\mid k \in \mathbb Z \},\{3k+1\mid k \in \mathbb Z \},\{3k+2\mid k \in \mathbb Z \}\}$ ??

Comment: $3 \mid (5x - 2y) \iff 3 \mid 2(x - y) \iff 3 \mid (x - y)$

Comment: The proofs gets even easier if you note $$3\mid 5x-2y\iff 3\mid 2x-2y \iff 3\mid x-y$$ hence the given relation is equivlant to : $x$ is congruent to $y$ mod $3$.

Comment: As for writing the partition into equivalence classes, rather than $\{3k\}$ which may be confused as a one-element set, it would be clearer to write $\{3k~:~k\in\Bbb Z\}$ to emphasize that there are in fact infinitely many elements in the set.  Similarly for the others.  Alternatively, you might opt to write the sets as $3\Bbb Z, 3\Bbb Z+1,$ and $3\Bbb Z+2$

Comment: As a representive for each class, you can choose the canonical triple $(0,1,2)$ The classes are then the sets of the numbers $3k,3k+1,3k+2$ respective where $k$ runs over the integers.

Comment: Just a notation issue. We formally write: $$(0)=\{x\mid \exists k(5x=3k)\}.$$ Given any $x,$ $5x=3k$ is true for at most one $k,$ and certainly not for all $k.$ Also, the elements of $(0)$ are the values $x,$ not the values $5x.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry but I didn't know that, surprisingly the notation I used is the one I learned in university

Comment: @Peter thank you

Comment: In general, the notation is $$\{y\in S\mid P(y)\}$$ where $S$ is a known set and $P(y)$ is some proposition on $y.$ We sometimes shorten this for convenience, so instead of $$\{y\in\mathbb Z\mid \exists k\in\mathbb Z(y=3k)\}$$ we write $$\{3k\mid k\in \mathbb Z\}$$ But the first part (before $\mid$ or $:$) is always the element, so $$\{5x=3k\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$$ is still wrong.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews i tried to fix it, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Murf-y I fixed your fixes. $\{k\in\mathbb Z\mid…\}$ was wrong,  because the elements are the $3k$ for $k\in\mathbb Z.$ $\{x,k\in\mathbb Z\mid…\}$ was wrong because the elements aren’t pairs, just the elements $x.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks again, one more question, how can I close the question and mark it as solved?

Comment: You can’t mark it solved unless someone posts a formal answer. You can delete it, however.